# Detecting the end of a writeStream in Node

Tags: node.js, file-io, stream

This is what I've got, and I keep getting an error because the file doesn't exist yet when I just do it sequentially.

How can I trigger an action upon the writeStream getting closed?

```
var fs = require('fs'), http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req){
    req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file'));


    /* i need to read the file back, like this or something: 
        var fcontents = fs.readFileSync(file);
        doSomethinWith(fcontents);
    ... the problem is that the file hasn't been created yet.
    */

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 32):

Writable streams have a [finish](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event that is emitted when the data is flushed.

Try the following;

```
var fs = require('fs'), http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var f = fs.createWriteStream('file');

    f.on('finish', function() {
        // do stuff
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('done');
    });

    req.pipe(f);
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Though I wouldnt re-read the file. You can use [through](https://github.com/dominictarr/through) to create a stream processor.

Comment: Wouldn't you then be assigning the finish handler after the finish event had occurred?

Comment: ie, wouldn't you want to execute the .on('finish' ... line before the .pipe(f) one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829976/assigning-event-handlers-after-the-events-may-have-already-been-emitted :)

Comment: When reading code I prefer binding to the event first but the comment in that question is correct. Those the above code work for you ?

Comment: dunno, didn't try yet.

Comment: the call to "ON" just registers a handler, its not doing anything else, the order isn't important

Comment: [In the docs it looks like the finish event is only emitted after the .end](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish)